# How to write code for rejecting expired client certificate (self-signed) in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate, trustmanager

I have a server as rest API in spring boot and client is Rest Template present in another spring boot application. Currently, in order to enable https,I have configured server.ssl related properties inside application.proeprties file of server like keystore and truststore details. (It's 2Way SSL)

I want my server to reject expired certificate presented by client.Currently, server is not checking validity date of client certificate automatically.

I am using keystore and truststore in jks format.

**How to reject expired client certificates??? I am not able to find code**.

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? my server is also accepting expired client certificate, thanks